# Can't set headers after they are sent when using dbquery multiple times

Tags: node.js, passport.js

> I get this error #Can't set headers after they are sent# when using dbquery multiple times.

Hi, I'm almost new to node.js and I can't figure out why this error appears. If I try with one dbquery then everything is ok. But if I use multiple query then it crashes.

```
router.get(
  '/auth/facebook/token',
  (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('facebook-token', (error, user, info) => {

                  if (user){
                    myDB.setUser(user.email,(err,pinfo) =>{
                      if (err) {
                       res.send(err);
                     }
                     else {
                       res.send(pinfo);    <- Crash at this line!!!      
                     }
                 });
            } 
      next();
    })(req,res, next);
  }
);




function setUser (email,  cb) {

  pool.query("INSERT INTO users (email,pinfo) VALUES (?,0)", email, (err, result) => {
    if(err){
      cb(err);
      return;
     }
    else{
      pool.query("SELECT pinfo FROM users WHERE email = ?", email,(err,pinfo) =>{
        cb(err,pinfo);
      });
    }
  }); 
}
```

Comment: why there is `(req, res, next)` at the end of `passport.auth` function?

Comment: I copied that part from somewhere without understanding why and if I remove that part code doesn't even function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling next middle layer function using next(). After sending the response to the user. Try without next or modify your logic to. Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks! Node.js program logic is quite unfamiliar but interesting.

Comment: if you are using express. Try to understand middle layer concept. If this answer was useful marked it as useful, so that it might help others.

Answer (score 0):

once you are used res.send you cannot use it again

it seems you are sending a response at two positions please check the logic thoroughly

Comment: Yeah, but I can't find where it went wrong.  After first query starts in setUser function, it calls next() in router.get. And then it gets into the setUser function again to check if there is an error, and then starts second query, and if no error, it starts res.send(pinfo) which causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Some Where you sending response twice and hence this error. R.sarkar is right take out next() call and add it somewhere you will want to continue with your next dbquery or else respond from top function only once and never call next().

Comment: Problem solved!  I moved next() into if error checker and no error appears. I'll have to learn about next function. Thanks!!